# PDFMiner can't read pdf forms that require Adobe Acrobat

Tags: python, adobe, acrobat, pdfminer, pdf-parsing

So My problem is that I am parsing through these PDF's to extract information with PDFminer and it works for most forms. However there are these other PDF's that won't open unless you use Adobe Acrobat. Unless using that it gives the message:

> The document you are trying to load requires Adobe Reader 8 or higher. You may not have the
>   Adobe Reader installed or your viewing environment may not be properly configured to use
>   Adobe Reader.
>
> For information on how to install Adobe Reader and configure your viewing environment please
>   see http://www.adobe.com/go/pdf_forms_configure.

This is fine when just trying to look at the document obviously you just download adobe acrobat and open it with that. But when using PDFMiner I can't figure out how to parse through the text because it doesn't use AA to open the files.

Sample PDF:
http://www.forms.ssb.gov.on.ca/mbs/ssb/forms/ssbforms.nsf/GetFileAttach/012-8551E~1/$File/8551E.pdf

Sample Code:

```
def extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            fake_file_handle = BytesIO()
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            yield text

            # close open handles
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()

def extract_text(pdf_path):
    with open("PDFText.txt", "wb") as text_file:
        for page in extract_text_by_page(pdf_path):
            print(page)
            print()
            text_file.write(page)
            text_file.write(bytes("\n\n", 'utf-8'))
    file=open("PDFText.txt")
    f = file.read()
    wordbank={"required", "shall", "must", "Name"}
    wordcount={}
    for word in wordbank:
        phonelist = re.findall("\\b(" + word + ")\\b(?i)", f )
        wordcount[word] = len(phonelist)

    file.close();
    return wordcount

def main():

    args = parse_cli()
    document = "Documents/" + args.file

    #Get Word count
    print(extract_text(document))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Linked sample PDF file contains an Adobe Acrobat fillable form which can be filled-out when viewing it with Acrobat Reader. Apparently PDFMiner can't handle them. Besides that, the file has been "SECURED" and password-protected, which may further impede you being able to read and parse it (with any software).

Comment: So is there nothing I can do about these fillable forms??? Can I batch convert them to another fie format potentially? Im kind of stuck here because Im scraping these documents but I'm not the one creating them, so I need to find a way to handle these forms.

I was already able to get past the SECURED part. not too hard to handle actually, just modified pdfminer to not check for security and try to run itself anyways, and since the password is just "" it works fine.

Comment: I don't know of any way. If you can open the file in a text editor, you may be able to figure out how Adobe has implemented form-filling (and parse the file yourself and either ignore or remove them). There's some information about PDF "form fields" in an old copy of their _PDF Reference v1.3_ document I have—you may be able to get a copy of it (or a newer one) somewhere on their website.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to parse the text using a PDF tool. The PDF file you link to is a Dynamic XFA file inside a PDF wrapper. PDFMiner will only see the wrapper, not the Dynamic XFA. The reason you need Acrobat to view these is that Acrobat will read the XML definition for the document and then render it as PDF. You might be able to use a PDF tool to get at the AcroForm/XFA dictionary and then an XML tool to parse the XFA but XFA is non-trivial.